quantification of novel miRNA expression in miRDeep2
I have some doubts about miRDeep2, which I am using for the first time.
I am analyzing data from Citrus Sinensis, which is a not well studied species, so it seems important to also conduct discovery of novel miRNAs, and in fact, it finds quite a few of them.
Doubt 1: The estimated probability that a novel miRNA detected is a true positive is not monotonous with the score. For example, the top scoring one has a score of 3.8e+3 and a probability of only 0.17 ± 0.14, while I find some with a score of 1.6 and a probability of 0.47 ± 0.07. How should these data be filtered?
Doubt 2: In the documentation and tutorials, I never see anyone doing expression quantification in 2 steps. They always run miRDeep2.pl only once, but in the "miRNA_expresses_all_sample" file, only miRNAs from miRBase are quantified (it seems). Wouldn't it be necessary to re-run the quantification also with the added novel miRNAs? Or maybe in my case, the novel miRNAs are all poor quality, and that's why they are not considered in the quantification?
As reference I put an extract of the novel miRNA result table


